# Powershell: code error for replacing character in string

Tags: powershell

i am VERY new to powershell and i am trying to create a script which will loop through all the subfolders of a folder, then for each sub folder loop through all the files and any which are older than 2 days copy to a new location. Below is the script i have currently but i keep getting an error "Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] does not contain a method named 'replace". Does anyone know what have done wrong

```
$RootFolder = "H:\route\Backup\Full_Backups"
$SubFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder -Directory
Foreach($SubFolder in $SubFolders)
{ 
    $NewPath = $SubFolder.replace('H:\', 'T:\')
    $threshold = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)
foreach ($SubFolder in Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $path -Directory) {
  # Construct sub-folder path
  $subPath = Join-Path $SubFolder.FullName "*\js\*"

  # Locate the files at *\js\*
  $files = Get-ChildItem $subPath -Recurse

  # Filter on Creation date
  $files = $files |Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $threshold }

  # Remove files
  $files |Copy-Item -Destination $NewPath -WhatIf
}
}
```

Comment: Change `$SubFolder.replace('H:\', 'T:\')` to `$SubFolder.FullName.Replace('H:\', 'T:\')`

Comment: Thank you so much. However i am now getting the error "The corresponding line is 'foreach ($SubFolder in Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $path -Directory) {  '. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Cannot bind argument to parameter 'LiteralPath' because it is null.  '.  Process Exit Code -1.  The step failed.,00:00:00,0,0,,,,0"

Comment: Makes sense - `$path` is never defined/assigned to anywhere :) Perhaps you want `$Subfolder |Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath -Directory` instead of `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $path -Directory`

Comment: thank you however i am now getting this message 'Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet.'

Comment: My bad, you need to remove `-LiteralPath` completely, `$Subfolder |Get-ChildItem -Directory`

Comment: So i have tried that and now i am getting a long error "At line:7 char:20  + foreach ($Subfolder |Get-ChildItem -Directory) {  +                    ~ Missing 'in' after variable in foreach loop.    At line:7 char:21  + foreach ($Subfolder |Get-ChildItem -Directory) {  +                     ~ An empty pipe element is not allowed.    At line:4 char:1  + {  + ~ Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.    At line:7 char:46  + foreach ($Subfolder |Get-ChildItem -Directory) {  +                                              ~ Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.  "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253234/discussion-between-mathias-r-jessen-and-jessica-nutt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for everyone's help. I have managed to fix it with the below:

```
$RootFolder = "H:\SQLServer\Backup\Full_Backups"
$subDir = (Get-ChildItem $RootFolder)
foreach($sub in $subDir) {
           $newpath = ($sub.FullName.replace('H:\','T:\'))
           $Source = $sub.FullName
           CD $Source
           Get-ChildItem ".\" -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-2))} | Where-Object { $_.Name} | Move-Item -Force -Destination "$newpath\"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Awesome, that you are stepping into the world of PowerShell :)

Here is an optimized version of the script. It gets all files recursively from the $RootFolder that are older than 2 days.
Then those files are copied to the new directory by replacing the drive letter.

```
$RootFolder = "H:\route\Backup\Full_Backups"

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder -Recurse -File | Where-Object CreationTime -lt $threshold

foreach ($file in $files) {
  $file | Copy-Item -Destination $PSItem.FullName.Replace('H:\', 'T:\')
}
```

What can be of great help sometimes is the cmdlet "Get-Member". Whenever you have objects at hand, you can always do "| gm", which is the alias for Get-Member. This will show you the object type and all properties and methods an object has.

Your initial problem was, that you tried to do a string replace on an array of objects. By doing the replace on $SubFolders.FullName, you do the replace on the string property of the objects.

Hope that helps!

Have fun with PowerShell!

Comment: Thank you however i am now getting the error ". SQL Server PowerShell provider error: Path SQLSERVER:\pp_env_01_copSSG_Aggregator does not exist. Please specify a valid path." which I don't understand as i have not specified that path in the code and it does not exisit

Comment: I feel like it would be better to use Move-Item. This will actually move the older files. Otherwise, you will constantly be copying the same files over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Per our discussion. This is what should get you to where you need to be.

**Condensed Version:**

```
$RootFolder = "H:\SQLServer\Backup\Full_Backups"

(Get-ChildItem $RootFolder -Recurse -File) 
| Where { ((get-date) - ($_.LastWriteTime)) -gt (new-timespan -days 2 -hours 0 -minutes 0) } 
| ForEach-Object -Begin {} -Process { Write-Host "Copying $($_.FullName) to $($_.FullName.Replace("H:\", "T:\"))"; 
Copy-Item -Path ($_.FullName) -Destination ($_.FullName.Replace("H:\", "T:\")) }
```

**Not Condensed:**

```
$RootFolder = "H:\SQLServer\Backup\Full_Backups"

$files = (Get-ChildItem $RootFolder -Recurse -File)


foreach ($f in $files){

if (((get-date) - ($f.LastWriteTime)) -gt (new-timespan -days 2 -hours 0 -minutes 0))
{
$oldpath = $f.FullName

$newPath = ($f.FullName.Replace("H:\", "T:\"))

Write-Host ($f.FullName)

Write-Host $newPath

Copy-Item -Path $oldpath -Destination $newPath
} else {

}
}
```